# uasort change array order before doing any 'user-defined' function

Tags: php

To start with, sorry if the title is not really clear.

Basically, I have an array containing 2 arrays that goes through a script that uses uasort.
Because for this specific array I didn't have the wanted behavior, I tried using a code as simple as possible that would reproduce my "bug":

```
<?php 
$myArray = array(
                 0 => array(
                      0 =>  array(  'field1' => "2.1",
                                    'filed2' => 1815199),
                      1 =>  "database.table",
                      2 =>  array(),
                      3 =>  NULL
                ),
                1 => array(
                      0 =>  array(  'field1' => "3.7",
                                    'filed2' => 1815199),
                      1 =>  "database.table",
                      2 =>  array(),
                      3 =>  NULL
                )
);

echo '@@~~}}~~@@  ';
var_dump( $myArray);

uasort( $myArray, "order_del_upd_ins" );

echo '@@~~{{~~@@  ';
var_dump( $myArray);

function order_del_upd_ins( $a, $b )
{
    echo '~~@@~~@@##@@~~@@~~ ';
    var_dump( $a);
    var_dump( $b);


   return 0;
}?>
```

So basically my first array contains the value 2.1, and the second array 3.7.

But when I print them, after going through the uasort (where I don't do anything), my second array gets first, and the first second:

```
@@~~}}~~@@  
array(2) {
[0] => array(4) {
      [0] =>
         array(2) {
           'field1' => string(3) "2.1"
           'filed2' => int(1815199)
        }
      [1] => string(14) "database.table"
      [2] => array(0) {}
      [3] => NULL
    }
[1] => array(4) {
     [0] => array(2) {
              'field1' => string(3) "3.7"
              'filed2' => int(1815199)
            }
     [1] => string(14) "database.table"
     [2] => array(0) {}
     [3] => NULL
    }
}

~~@@~~@@##@@~~@@~~ 
array(4) {
[0] =>
    array(2) {
       'field1' => string(3) "3.7"
       'filed2' => int(1815199)
    }
[1] => string(14) "database.table"
[2] => array(0) {}
[3] => NULL
}

array(4) {
[0] => array(2) {
    'field1' => string(3) "2.1"
    'filed2' => int(1815199)
    }
[1] => string(14) "database.table"
[2] => array(0) {}
[3] => NULL
}

@@~~{{~~@@  
array(2) {
[1] => array(4) {
       [0] =>
          array(2) {
            'field1' => string(3) "3.7"
            'filed2' => int(1815199)
         }
       [1] => string(14) "database.table"
       [2] => array(0) {}
       [3] => NULL
   }
[0] => array(4) {
       [0] =>
          array(2) {
            'field1' => string(3) "2.1"
            'filed2' => int(1815199)
          }
       [1] => string(14) "database.table"
       [2] => array(0) {}
       [3] => NULL
   }
}
```

So basiccaly, I have an array of 2 elements, going to a function uasort that doesnt do anything, but as soon as it goes in, the elements are not ordered properly anymore.

According to php manual:

> uasort — Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and
>   maintain index association

So from what I understand, if I don't specify anything in my 'user-defined' function, nothing should change in my array right ??

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The return of the user-defined sort function is going to determine how the array is sorted. For example, the following would sort in ascending order...

```
function order_del_upd_ins( $a, $b )
{
   return $a > $b;
}
```

You say "if I don't specify anything in my sort function", but you do specify 0 which equates to $a and $b being equal.

Check out the explanation here..
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you can see, when I print $a and $b (first thing in my function), $a is the second element, and $b is the first element. So I am guessing that is already wrong ?